# iOS web view remove the history

Tags: ios, uiwebview, uiwebviewdelegate

How can I remove the history of web view so that webview's can go back method returns NO instead of Yes.

Any ideas on how to do that

I couldn't find any way to go back to the first page loaded in the URL.

If I could get answer to any of these it'd be great .

Googling didn't help